# How to average per row based on number of NAs columns

Tags: r

I am having the following dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, NA, 1,5),
             b = c(NA, NA, 2, 3),
             c = c(NA, 5, NA, 5),
             d = c(3, NA, NA, NA))
```

I want to average per row all these variables.
But I want to R to return NA when there is only one value per each row.

How am I going to do that?

The results should look like that:

```
a  b  c  d  average
NA NA NA 3    NA
NA NA 5  NA   NA
1  2  NA NA   1.5
5  3  5  NA   4,33
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Similar to SamR

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = c(NA, NA, 1,5),
                 b = c(NA, NA, 2, 3),
                 c = c(NA, 5, NA, 5),
                 d = c(3, NA, NA, NA))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(average = ifelse(sum(!is.na(cur_data())) <= 1, 
                          NA, 
                          mean(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE)
         ))

# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c     d average
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1    NA    NA    NA     3   NA   
2    NA    NA     5    NA   NA   
3     1     2    NA    NA    1.5 
4     5     3     5    NA    4.33
```

With `case_when()`

```
df %>%  
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(average = case_when(sum(!is.na(cur_data())) <= 1 ~ NA_real_, 
                             TRUE ~ mean(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Self-selecting columns

```
df %>%  
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(average = case_when(sum(!is.na(cur_data())) <= 1 ~ NA_real_, 
                             TRUE ~ rowMeans(across(c(a, b)), na.rm = TRUE)
                             )
         )

df %>% 
  select(a, b) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(average = ifelse(sum(!is.na(cur_data())) <= 1, 
                          NA, 
                          mean(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE)
  ))
```

Comment: What if I have 3 columns that I need to average but still I want R to return NA when there is at least 2 values in each of these 3 rows? I am trying to use the above code but it does not work. Thanks,

Comment: @user13069688 Check out the last one I have added, select the columns in `select()` should satisfy this condition

Comment: Yes but like that my other variables are removed. By that I mean the variables that i have apart from a,b,c,d.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is first checking the index of rows which have at least more than 1 non-NA values and then calculate the `rowMeans` for these rows like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, NA, 1,5),
                 b = c(NA, NA, 2, 3),
                 c = c(NA, 5, NA, 5),
                 d = c(3, NA, NA, NA))

index <- rowSums(!is.na(df)) > 1 
df[index, "average"] <- rowMeans(df[index, ], na.rm = TRUE)
df
#>    a  b  c  d  average
#> 1 NA NA NA  3       NA
#> 2 NA NA  5 NA       NA
#> 3  1  2 NA NA 1.500000
#> 4  5  3  5 NA 4.333333
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse()` to set the value of `average` to `NA` where there is 1 or 0 values which are not `NA`, and otherwise to the `rowMeans()`.

```r
df$average  <- ifelse(
  rowSums(!is.na(df)) <=1, 
  NA,
  rowMeans(df, na.rm = T)
)

df
#    a  b  c  d  average
# 1 NA NA NA  3       NA
# 2 NA NA  5 NA       NA
# 3  1  2 NA NA 1.500000
# 4  5  3  5 NA 4.333333
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. Is there a way to do it with dplyr? I am trying to use mutate like the following:

df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, NA, 1,5),
                 b = c(NA, NA, 2, 3),
                 c = c(NA, 5, NA, 5),
                 d = c(3, NA, NA, NA)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(average = mean(c(a,b,c,d), na.rm = TRUE))

Answer (score 0):

In `tidyverse`, we may create the condition in `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(average = case_when(across(everything(), complete.cases) %>% 
       reduce(`+`) %>% 
       magrittr::is_greater_than(1) 
    ~ rowMeans(across(everything()), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
   a  b  c  d  average
1 NA NA NA  3       NA
2 NA NA  5 NA       NA
3  1  2 NA NA 1.500000
4  5  3  5 NA 4.333333
```